# Update: Redux reducer is not beeing called to change CSS classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and react-redux.
I am trying to change CSS classes when the user clicks on a `<div>` tag rendered dynamically. The code is working when I try to set the state locally, but when I want to use redux I get undefined value of the array in which should be stored the `event.target.id`. Could you please tell me where I am wrong?
I will start with action:

```
export const selectAttr = (e)=>{     
    return (dispatch) => {
        return(
            dispatch({
                type: SELECT_ATTRIBUTES,
                payload: e.target.id
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
 const initialState = {
    selectedAttr: [],
}
 

export default function selectAttrReducer (state = initialState, action) {
    let tmp = [...state.selectedAttr]
    function attributes() {
        if (tmp.length === 0) {
            tmp = [...tmp, action.payload];
            return tmp;
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                if (action.payload.split(":")[0] === tmp[i].split(":")[0]) {
                    tmp = [...tmp.filter(el => el.split(":")[0] !== action.payload.split(":")[0]), action.payload];

                } else {
                    tmp = [...tmp, action.payload];
                }
            }
            return tmp;
        }
    }
    switch(action.type){
        case SELECT_ATTRIBUTES:
           attributes()
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedAttr: [...state.selectedAttr, ...tmp]
            }
        default:
            return state    
    }
}
```

Fragments of JSX:

```
<div>
    {attributes.map((attr, index) => (
        <div key={attr.id}>
            {/* attribute name */}
            <p className="pdp-attr">{attr.name}:</p>

            {/* attribute representation */}
            <div className="swatch-flex">
                {attributes[index].items.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <div
                            onClick={this.props.selectAttr}
                            className={
                                selectedAttr?.indexOf(
                                    attributes[index].id.concat(":", item.id)
                                ) === -1
                                    ? "pdp-box"
                                    : "pdp-box isSelected"
                            }
                            id={attributes[index].id.concat(":", item.id)}></div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        selectedAttr: state.selectedAttr,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { selectAttr })(Component);
```

**Update:**
Looks like reducer is called, but `selectedAttr` array has thousands of items. I updated the code also.
I am using also `redux-persist`. Can be, because of this one?

Comment: `return {...state, ...tmp}` Idk what the heck spreading an array and an object together will do but I'm betting it's not what you meant to do. tmp is a list and state is an object.

I'm also worried you have state outside of your reducer. Reducers are almostly always functions of state + action. Pull tmp into the local scope of the function.

Comment: If I bring tmp inside the function throws, "'tmp' is not defined" here ` ({    ...state.selectedAttr, ...tmp})` . I checked the whole application and there is no state ouside the reducer

Comment: `let tmp = [...initialState.selectedAttr]` no reason this won't work

Comment: @nlta I have tried this way, but same results. The reducer is looking like this rigth now. But still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reducer was called, but becasue it is a "pure" function, ([Rules of reducers](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers)) I moved the filter method inside of a selector.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the reducer isn't being called?

**This code is wrong:**

```js
return {
    ...state, ...tmp
}
```

***(don't)** Try this:**
See @nlta's comment.

```js
// must wrap in parenthesis to return an object
return ({
    ...state, ...tmp
})
```

Comment: I have a console.log(e.target.id) in action and everytime I click it logs. I loged also the props for this component and  selectedAttr is undefined. I change the code to         
`return ({ ...state.selectedAttr, ...tmp })` and it is same. It renders like all div tags are selected by default